# Cannot upgrade AMD 64 bit Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10?

Tags: upgrade

Software updater shows that 13.04 is current and an upgrade to 13.10 is available. However, upon hitting the upgrade button, typing in the password and hitting authenticate results in nothing happening.  I do not get the 13.10 welcome screen at all.  No error messages and the updater just goes away.

What is wrong?

Comment: its 13.10 as in year 2013 and month 10. 13.1 would be a January release. There was no 13.1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try to upgrade via the command line, try the instructions [here](http://lawrit.lawr.ucdavis.edu/it-help-center/how-to/upgrading-ubuntu-via-command-line)

In a nutshell, run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```